# how can i use res.sendfile method in a post request

Tags: node.js, forms, express, post, sendfile

I have a form and I want it to use post request in it
what I wanna do is ask for a username and password in the form and send the details back to the server from there check for credentials and send the static page if its correct

but whenever I use res.sendFile in a post request it always says cannot post
Pls help

I am trying to do it something like this

```
app.post('/main', (req, res) => {
```

res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/somepage.html")}

Comment: Could you please show some relevant code?

Comment: Can't really help without seeing the relevant client and server code.